# GridView with frozen Header and First Four columns?

Tags: asp.net, css

I need to develop a GridView with scroll and frozen first columns and Header. I did a huge search in the web and I found many resources that do not work with me all and I don't know why. For example, now I am using [this simple tutorial](http://portal-management.blogspot.com/2009/05/gridview-with-fixed-header.html) for doing that but I got the following bad looking:
[image]

For freezing the header, I used this CSS code:

```
<style>
            .grid-header
            {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 11px;
            background-color: #7A9FCB;
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: left;
            position: relative;
            top:expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollTop-2);
            left:expression(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.scrollLeft-1);
            right:1px;
            }
        </style>
```

**Could anyone help me with this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to split the header and the content in 2 divs, the one is the header and the rest that scrolls is the content.

Here is an example

http://fixedheadertable.com/livedemos/

Comment: Is there any example for using this JQuery with the GridView?

Comment: @AliAhmed The trick is done with css and divs, not need jQuery, it may help if you do that onthefly, but first you need to understand what you must do.

Comment: Ok could you please tell me what I should do. I am really struggling with this issue and this is why I am asking here.

Comment: @AliAhmed read this example, http://fixedheadertable.com/livedemos/ its explain it very well, and its jQuery also. You split the table into 2 divs, the one is scroll and the other the header is static.

Answer (score 0):

Eep! Expressions in css are quite costly in performance. They re-evaluate your css for every pixel of your page's or (in some instances) mouse's movements, so unless you absolutely have no other options, I would avoid using them.

Have you tried using CSS `position: fixed` for the parts you want to freeze-frame?

Comment: your suggestion will now freeze the header, but it will make it inside the div. How to freeze it?

Comment: Do you have a code example that I can take a look at? It's a bit hard to grasp without an example. You could try copying your code into jsfiddle.net or dabblet.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
       <tr><td>
           <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2">
               <Columns>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="LblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EmpId") %>'></asp:Label>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="LblGender" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EmpName") %>'></asp:Label>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hobbies">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:Label ID="LblHobbies" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EmpSalary") %>'></asp:Label>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>


               </Columns>
               <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
               <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
               <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
               <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
               <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
               <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
               <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
               <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
               <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
           </asp:GridView>
           </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by posting an explanation of what you've done. It may not be clear to the person asking how you've solved their problem.